# Problem with if condition on a "random walk" script

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make the coordinate "x" randomly move in the interval [-1,1]. However, my code works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't. I tried ShellCheck but it says "no issues detected!". I'm new to conditionals, am I using them wrong?

I'm running this on the windows subsystem for linux. I'm editing it on nano. Since I have a script that will plot 200 of these "random walks", the code should work consistenly, but I really don't understant why it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
x=0
for num in {1..15}
do
  r=$RANDOM
  if [[ $r -lt 16383 ]]
  then
    p=1
  else
    p=-1
  fi
  if [[ $x -eq $p ]]
  then
    x=$(echo "$x-$p" | bc )
  else
    x=$(echo "$x+$p" | bc )
  fi
  echo "$num $x"
done
```

I expect something like this:

```
1 -1
2 0
3 1
4 0
5 1
6 0
7 1
8 0
9 1
10 0
11 -1
12 0
13 1
14 0
15 1
```

But the usual output is something like this:

```
1 1
2 0
3 -1
4 0
5 -1
6 0
7 -1
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
8
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
9
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
10
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
11
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
12
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
13
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
14
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
15
```

Always stopping after a -1.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Just for your information, if `x == p` you can just set x to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `bash`:

```
 x=$(( x - p ))
```

or

```
 (( x -= p ))
```

and you don't need `bc`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `x=$(echo "$x-$p" | bc )` with `x=$(echo "$x-($p)" | bc )` to avoid `echo "-1--1" | bc`.

Comment: This is the actual bug-fix!

Comment: It is actually enough to place a space inbetween: `x = $(echo "$x - $p" | bc )` and even better with a HERESTRING, `x=$(bc <<< "$x - $p")`

Answer (score 1):

One-liner equivalents to the OP's 18-line random walk script, using `bash` *arithmetic evaluation*:

1. `x=0; printf '%-5s\n' {1..15}\ $(( x=(RANDOM%2 ? 1 : -1) * (x==0) ))`
2. `x=0; printf '%-5s\n' {1..15}\ $(( x=( x ? 0 : (RANDOM%2 ? 1 : -1) ) ))`

Sample output of either, (the *2nd* column will vary between runs):

```
1 -1 
2 0  
3 -1 
4 0  
5 1  
6 0  
7 1  
8 0  
9 -1 
10 0 
11 1 
12 0 
13 -1
14 0 
15 -1
```

---

How it works:

- `echo {1..15}\ $(( ...some code... ))` prints the numbers *1* to
  *15* followed by *15* instances of whatever result in the `$(( ... ))` code returns.  One flaw with this approach is that with the resulting *15* pairs of numbers, (*e.g.* `1 -1`, `2 0`, *etc.*), each appears to `bash` as one string, rather than *30* separate numbers.
- `(RANDOM%2)`: the `%` is a [*modulo operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Notation) and here returns the remainder when divided by `2`, which is either `0` or `1`.
- `(x==0)`: `$x` can be one of three numbers, but if the previous value of `$x` was `-1` or `1` the only legal random step is `0`, so we only need a random number if the previous value of `$x` was `0`.
- The `if` logic is replaced with shortcuts of the form *`(expr?expr:expr)`*; these use the same logic as the OP script.

Comment: This actually does not do the random walk. You made a nice short version of how to compute `p` (in the OP's question) on an alternative way using modulo. You actually do not perform the summations with `x`.

Comment: @kvantour, Egad, you're right, thank you.   The telltale output error is that my current code can step from `1` to `-1` with no `0` between.  Fix pending.

Comment: @kvantour, See revised answer.